# OEM cables don't match new LED mirrors, need specialized adapters?

Tags: fuse, mirrors, led

I replaced the mirrors on my Honda with LED mirrors after one of them broke off and I don't think the cables match, so I'm unable to control the mirror electronically. A few other sets of cables came with them with no directions and I assume they are extensions to the fuse panel. The cables on the original have sharp point male ends that plug into a few chosen points in a 15 or so pronged female connector. The ones provided with replacement look like something that would hook onto a brake cable. Also the end connectors on the extensions are single pronged as the fuse inputs require double prongs. I removed the original on the passenger side and it is still assembled with the end connector so I can follow the wiring pattern that way but I need to find a specialized kind of adapter.

Comment: With the amount of information you've given, there is no way to answer this question. Have you tried looking at the manufacturer's website? At least post up exactly which make/model/type of mirrors they are, as well as vehicle information. I know you have a Civic, but beyond that, I don't remember. How about some pictures of what you're talking about? Give us something to go on, please, or I will vote to close this as unclear what you are asking.